# For Loop for oracle process status

Tags: linux, loops, unix, process

I am trying to find all database status that were running. To achive it tried loop in the logic for all db_sid that are currently running  program running but wrong results even though database and listners are up when i checked manually
existing oracle instance running.

`[oracle@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx~]$ ps -ef|grep smon
oracle   15093     1  0 Nov08 ?        00:00:30 ora_smon_orcl
oracle   15486     1  0 Nov08 ?        00:00:30 ora_smon_orcltest`

Now trying to get each instance that is running ..i.e only db_sid name by omitting ora_smon_ and getting only name 
for ora_smon_orcl ==> orcl
for ora_smon_orcltest ==> orcltest

```
for db_sid in `ps -ef | grep smon | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $8 }' | cut -d '_' -f3` ; do
echo $db_sid
db_sid_pro="ora_smon_$db_sid"
echo $db_sid_pro
source /home/oracle/$db_sid
ora_home=$ORACLE_HOME
echo $ORACLE_HOME
case "$db_sid" in
"$db_sid_pro")
echo "hi"
tag="true"
echo $tag
msg="$db_sid database instance is running"
echo "$db_sid_pro database process is running"
;;
*)
if [ -e $ora_home/dbs/spfile$db_sid.ora ];then
msg="database is down"
echo "database is down"
tag="false"
else
tag="false"
msg="Incorrect database SID - $db_sid. Please provide the correct database SID"
echo "Incorrect database SID - $db_sid. Please provide the correct database SID"
fi
;;
esac
```

the output shown on terminal is below: but manually i checked databse is up and listener also up..May be i am missing something in programming logic here not really database issue.

```
orcl
ora_smon_orcl
/dbusr/app/oracle/product/12102
database is down
Oracle listener is down please make it up
database is down
Oracle listener is down please make it up
orcltest
ora_smon_orcltest
/dbusr/app/oracle/product/12102
database is down
Oracle listener is down please make it up
database is down
Oracle listener is down please make it u
```

However I find below is causing trouble..because when I put some debug echo its not displaying "hi"

```
case "$db_sid" in
"$db_sid_pro")
echo "hi"
tag="true"
echo $tage
```

and also i have manually checked for below line.. files are indeed exist as per below condition

```
if [ -e $ora_home/dbs/spfile$db_sid.ora ];then
```

Any suggestion or correction please.

Thanks in advance